# Database for development

Tags: plugin-development, database

While building plugins one of my biggest annoyances is that my development machine does not match a real world install. What I mean here is that my databases are lacking. I'll code something thinking it'll work (since it does during development) then find out it doesn't because I neglected a minor detail missing from my local db. Even my own online install doesn't contain a full database.

Is there available a set of db's pre-filled out with the usual WP content? Or even a script to auto add rows and columns? I'm looking for user's of varying roles, custom post types, taxonomies, comments etc, which can be dropped in for development purposes only? If not does anybody have a backup from an old site they would like to share?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for the Theme Unit Test data: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test

Download the `.xml` file and import with the [WordPress importer plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/), and you should be good to go.